# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty } \frac{n^{2}}{n+1}=\infty $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Please check my proof

Suppose $M>0$ is given, and we want find $N$ that $n>N$.

Consider:

$$\frac{n^{2}}{n+1}< \frac{n^{2}}{n}=n$$

Then

$$n<M \iff \frac{1}{M}< n$$

Then choose $\frac{1}{M}\leq N$ for every $n>N.$

Therefore

$\frac{1}{M}\leq N< n$  and $\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{n^{2}}{n+1}=\infty.$

Comment: A quick note tip regarding MathJax/Latex,  to write $x\to\infty$ we use `\to` for the arrow instead of `->`, as it typsets more naturally.

Comment: ^And what's with $m$ and $M$ ?

Comment: What is $m$? What happens when $M={1\over2}$?

Comment: Sorry I mistype m instead M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M>0$.$$\frac{n^2}{1+n}=n\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)\geq \frac{n}{2}.$$

If you take $N=2M$ then, $$\frac{n^2}{1+n}\geq M$$
for all $n\geq N$.